# Why isn't a jdbc connection pool created?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jdbc, glassfish

I'm developing a simple Java EE application with an EAR-file including JAR- and WAR-files. In the EAR-project under EarContent/META-INF I have the following glassfish-resources.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE resources PUBLIC "-//GlassFish.org//DTD GlassFish Application Server 3.1 Resource Definitions//EN" "http://glassfish.org/dtds/glassfish-resources_1_5.dtd">
<resources>
    <jdbc-connection-pool name="java:app/jdbc/test" res-type="javax.sql.XADataSource" datasource-classname="org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientXADataSource">
        <property name="serverName" value="localhost"/>
        <property name="portNumber" value="1527"/>
        <property name="databaseName" value="test"/>
        <property name="createDatabase" value="create"/>
        <property name="user" value="APP"/>
        <property name="password" value="APP"/>
    </jdbc-connection-pool>
    <jdbc-resource jndi-name="java:app/jdbc/test" pool-name="java:app/jdbc/test"/>
</resources>
```

In the EJB-project under META-INF I have the following persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="events" transaction-type="JTA">
        <description>Manages events, users and comments</description>
        <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
        <jta-data-source>java:app/jdbc/test</jta-data-source>
        <class>com.hank.entity.Question</class>
        <class>com.hank.entity.QuizWalk</class>
        <class>com.hank.entity.User</class>
        <class>com.hank.entity.QuizWalkParticipants</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="create-tables"/>
            <property name="eclipselink.logging.connection" value="false"/>
            <property name="eclipselink.logging.level.sql" value="ALL"/>
            <property name="eclipselink.logging.parameters" value="true"/>
            <property name="eclipselink.logging.session" value="false"/>
            <property name="eclipselink.logging.thread" value="false"/>
            <property name="eclipselink.logging.timestamp" value="false"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

I have a running Derby server and the port number is correct. The application is working except that no database is created. What can be wrong? This approach worked with Glassfish 3.1.

Hank

Comment: Can you post your stacktrace?

Comment: I didn't get any error messages, hence no stacktrace.

Answer (score 2):

I was struggling with a similar problem a month ago. In the very end, I had following state in my XMLs (in comparison to yours):

**glassfish-resources.xml**

- I added `URL` and `driverClass` properties to `glassfish-resources.xml`
- Not sure if it is mandatory to do so, but I had different values for
  `jndi-name` and `pool-name`
- I used mysql so my `jdbc-connection-pool` tag had these two attributes:
  `res-type="javax.sql.DataSource",

  datasource-classname="com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource"`
- No `createDatabase` property

Edit: here is my glassfish-resources (it was actually auto generated by netbeans, I just added proper credentials and resource names)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE resources PUBLIC "-//GlassFish.org//DTD GlassFish Application Server 3.1 Resource Definitions//EN" "http://glassfish.org/dtds/glassfish-resources_1_5.dtd">
<resources>
    <jdbc-connection-pool allow-non-component-callers="false" 
    associate-with-thread="false" 
    connection-creation-retry-attempts="0" 
    connection-creation-retry-interval-in-seconds="10" 
    connection-leak-reclaim="false" 
    connection-leak-timeout-in-seconds="0" 
    connection-validation-method="auto-commit" 
    datasource-classname="com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource" 
    fail-all-connections="false" idle-timeout-in-seconds="300" 
    is-connection-validation-required="false" 
    is-isolation-level-guaranteed="true" lazy-connection-association="false" 
    lazy-connection-enlistment="false" match-connections="false" 
    max-connection-usage-count="0" max-pool-size="32" 
    max-wait-time-in-millis="60000" name="MY_POOL" 
    non-transactional-connections="false" 
    pool-resize-quantity="2" 
    res-type="javax.sql.DataSource" 
    statement-timeout-in-seconds="-1" 
    steady-pool-size="8" 
    validate-atmost-once-period-in-seconds="0"
    wrap-jdbc-objects="false">
        <property name="serverName" value="localhost"/>
        <property name="portNumber" value="3306"/>
        <property name="databaseName" value="nippon"/>
        <property name="User" value="root"/>
        <property name="Password" value="root"/>
        <property name="URL" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/nippon"/>
        <property name="driverClass" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
    </jdbc-connection-pool>
    <jdbc-resource enabled="true" jndi-name="JNDI_NAME" object-type="user" pool-name="MY_POOL"/>
</resources>
```

**persistence.xml**

```
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence 
http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="UNIT_NAME" transaction-type="JTA">
        <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
        <jta-data-source>JNDI_NAME</jta-data-source>
        <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="create"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

According to the current GF documentation, `glassfish-resources.xml` is only used for generation of server resources (connection pool and JDBC resource), and database generation is easily managed from `persistence.xml`.

Comment: Could you please share your glassfish-resources.xml? Seems like the Glassfish-server isn't ignoring my glassfish-resources.xml but some some property is missing.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that Glassfish v4 configuration of jdbc datasource changed a bit from v3. You need to specify `connectionAttributes` property to create the database. Property `createDatabase` is not documented and probably ignored.

Property `connectionAttributes` is not well documented either, but you may find an example in Glassfish 4 PDF documentation ([Administration Guide](https://glassfish.java.net/docs/4.0/administration-guide.pdf) - section Administering JDBC connectino pools), or in sources of [Payara server](https://github.com/payara/Payara/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=connectionAttributes), which is derived from Glassfish 4.

Comment: Any more suggestions?